# Random numbers picked from array that sums up to a float

Tags: c++, random

So I try to pick 15 random numbers from my array that their sum adds up to 47826.53 but doesn't work.

> My **`k`** is not **incrementing**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  float x[23] =
    { 6653.05, 1939.89, 6649.05, 2755.74, 5270.62, 6216.57, 4812.92, 7919.50,
    4807.46, 1698.00, 849.01, 1415.01, 1698.00, 4811.61, 1698.21, 7355.99,
    4817.37,
    566.75, 2266.47, 1699.86, 3966.33, 849.93, 849.93
  };
  int v[22] = { 0 };
  float s = 0;
  int k = 0;
  int RandIndex = 0;

  while (s != 47826.53)
    {
      RandIndex = rand () % 24;
      if (v[RandIndex] == 0 && RandIndex != 0)
    {
      s = s + x[RandIndex];
      k++;
      v[RandIndex] = 1;
      cout << s << " ";
    }
      if (k > 15 || s > 47826.53)
    {

      for (int i = 0; i <= 22; i++)
        v[i] = 0;
      k = 0;
    }

    }
  cout << s;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 23; i++)
    if (v[i] != 0)
      cout << "Number :" << x[i];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is the full code https://pastebin.com/p8vUFAbt

Comment: Why do you expect 15 random numbers to just happen to add up to `47826.53`, specifically? Even if there exists a subset of 15 numbers that adds up to this total, the probability of picking exactly that subset is small, so you are going to be in that loop for a long time. What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? What problem are you really trying to solve? This looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Well I know that there are 15 numbers that add up to that . They are payments and I know that 15 were paid from 23 but don't know which ones . @Igor Tandetnik

Comment: Also, your indexes are off. `rand () % 24` produces a number from 0 to 23 inclusive. Valid indexes into `x[23]` are 0 through 22; valid indexes into `v[22]` are 0 through 21. You inexplicably discard `RandIndex` of 0, and the index of 22 or 23 would go out of bounds of `v` or `x` or both.

Comment: And you believe trying combinations at random is the best way to find the right one? My guess would be, the universe will suffer heat death sooner than your program reaches the answer.

Comment: Then what`s the best way to find the numbers

Comment: Even just systematically trying every subset of would be enormously faster. There are only `choice(23, 15) == 490314` such combinations.

Comment: the closest I could get is 47831.42