# Numpy array with the given values and the sum equal 1

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to create random np.array with values including only [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, ... 0.9, 0.95, 1] with the sum of the values = 1

I know how to create a random array, for example, of 5 elements, so that the sum is equal to 1:

```
array = np.random.random(5)
array /= np.sum(array)
```

But how can I make that the values in this array are only from [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, ... 0.9, 0.95, 1]?

Upd. This method works, but maybe there are more pythonic ways. 100 arrays

```
sets = []
while len(sets) < 100:
    array = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 1.05, 0.05), 5)
    if np.sum(array) == 1:
        sets.append(array)
```

Comment: Do you want to pick a fixed number of random numbers? having both conditions would eliminate complete uniform randomness from it if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can't you just shuffle the array with desired values and sum? Something like `numpy.random.shuffle(numpy.arange(0.05, 1.05, 0.05))`

Comment: I want to pick fixed numbers [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, ... 0.9, 0.95, 1] but in random order so that the sum = 1

Comment: @JSer1 Can your resulting `arr` contains repeated elements from the given list of values?

Comment: Yes, repeated elements are ok.

Comment: Knapsack problem with weight=value and capacity 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to the following problem:

1. Choose 5 random integers in `[1, 20]` with a sum of `20`, where the integers appear in random order.
2. Divide the chosen integers by 20.

The Python code below shows how this can be implemented. It has the following advantages:

- It does not use rejection sampling.
- It chooses uniformly at random from among all combinations that meet the requirements.

It's based on an algorithm by John McClane, which he posted as an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61520472/815724).  I [describe the algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525097/815724) in another answer.

```
import random # Or secrets

def _getSolTable(n, mn, mx, sum):
        t = [[0 for i in range(sum + 1)] for j in range(n + 1)]
        t[0][0] = 1
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            for j in range(0, sum + 1):
                jm = max(j - (mx - mn), 0)
                v = 0
                for k in range(jm, j + 1):
                    v += t[i - 1][k]
                t[i][j] = v
        return t

def intsInRangeWithSum(numSamples, numPerSample, mn, mx, sum):
        """ Generates one or more combinations of
           'numPerSample' numbers each, where each
           combination's numbers sum to 'sum' and are listed
           in any order, and each
           number is in the interval '[mn, mx]'.
            The combinations are chosen uniformly at random.
               'mn', 'mx', and
           'sum' may not be negative.  Returns an empty
           list if 'numSamples' is zero.
            The algorithm is thanks to a _Stack Overflow_
          answer (`questions/61393463`) by John McClane.
          Raises an error if there is no solution for the given
          parameters.  """
        adjsum = sum - numPerSample * mn
        # Min, max, sum negative
        if mn < 0 or mx < 0 or sum < 0:
            raise ValueError
        # No solution
        if numPerSample * mx < sum:
            raise ValueError
        if numPerSample * mn > sum:
            raise ValueError
        if numSamples == 0:
            return []
        # One solution
        if numPerSample * mx == sum:
            return [[mx for i in range(numPerSample)] for i in range(numSamples)]
        if numPerSample * mn == sum:
            return [[mn for i in range(numPerSample)] for i in range(numSamples)]
        samples = [None for i in range(numSamples)]
        table = _getSolTable(numPerSample, mn, mx, adjsum)
        for sample in range(numSamples):
            s = adjsum
            ret = [0 for i in range(numPerSample)]
            for ib in range(numPerSample):
                i = numPerSample - 1 - ib
                # Or secrets.randbelow(table[i + 1][s])
                v = random.randint(0, table[i + 1][s] - 1)
                r = mn
                v -= table[i][s]
                while v >= 0:
                    s -= 1
                    r += 1
                    v -= table[i][s]
                ret[i] = r
            samples[sample] = ret
        return samples
```

Example:

```
weights=intsInRangeWithSum(
   # One sample
   1,
   # Count of numbers per sample
   5,
   # Range of the random numbers
   1, 20,
   # Sum of the numbers
   20)
# Divide by 100 to get weights that sum to 1
weights=[x/20.0 for x in weights[0]]
```

---

In any case, your code below:

```
array = np.random.random(5)
array /= np.sum(array)
```

...does not result in a uniform random combination of numbers with a sum of 1.  Instead, use the following instead of that code, noting that uniform arrivals are *exponentially* spaced, not uniformly spaced. (To be clear, this does not solve the problem in your question; this is only an observation.  Never mind the fact that `numpy.random.*` functions are [now legacy functions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/legacy.html) since NumPy 1.17, in part because they use global state.)

```
array = np.random.exponential(5)
array /= np.sum(array)
```