# Generate a discrete probability distribution from constraints

Tags: python, random, probability

Given:

- A discrete probability distribution over `n-bit` integers represented as a list `ys` of floats (i.e. `sum(ys) == 1`)
- a parameter `eps` such that `0 < eps < 0.5`

I want to generate a new probability distribution over `n-bit` integers, `xs`, such that the following holds:

```
(1) (forall) i in range(0, 2**n): 
    (1 - eps) <= xs[i] / ys[i] <= (1 + eps)

(2) sum(xs) == 1
```

My (naive) starting point is this:

```py
for i in range(2**n):
    xs[i] = uniform(ys[i] * (1 - eps), ys[i] * (1 + eps))
```

but obviously `sum(xs)` may not be 1, and normalizing `xs` may break condition `(1)`.

---

It seems to me that there *should* be a way to generate such a list where both constraints are met. Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: You can get more accurate results if you use fractions rather than floating-point numbers (use the `fractions` module; e.g., `fractions.Fraction(5,100)`).  Then, there wouldn't be a need for the `eps` parameter if all it serves is to bound the floating-point error.

Comment: See also my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525097/815724

Comment: The goal here is to have two distributions which are "multiplicatively" close, meaning that for all items in the support, the ratio is within `1-eps` and `1+eps`. I am not concerned with floating-point error.

Comment: for each xs[i] limit the error to eps/2**n. After they are generated, normalization will work. I don't think you can have uniform on entire ys[i] * (1 - eps), ys[i] * (1 + eps)

Comment: a looser bound is to limit the error to eps/n. This by law of large numbers, the errors will cancel enough other and 'mostly' it should work. If it doesn;t regenerate.