# Efficiently sampling a random 0-1 sequence of length l with at least k ones

Tags: random, sequence

Is there a way to efficiently sample a random 0-1 sequence of length l with at least k ones? When k << l/2, doing reject sampling would be good enough. But when k is relatively large it is trickier.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61393463/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-generate-n-random-integers-in-a-range-that-have-a-g

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an efficient way to generate N random integers in a range that have a given sum or average?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61393463/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-generate-n-random-integers-in-a-range-that-have-a-g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer a **rejection-free** approach, there is always the possibility to:

1. precompute the total number **t** of possible objects, using some combinatorics
2. draw a random integer number (the “*rank*”) between 0 and t-1 inclusive
3. compute the object from its rank, again using some combinatorics

The process of getting the object from its rank is known as ***unranking***.

For example, consider bit strings that are 8 bits long, so n=8, with k at least 5. So k lies in [5, 6, 7, 8].

To compute t, we need to sum the number of [*combinations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of k items out of n=8 items. Chosen items (bits) are set to 1, and the other ones are set to 0.

In order to do this, we have to use *binomial coefficients* *C(n,k)* as found in the [Pascal Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Say we use the Python programming language for that. We need some Python code to compute a binomial coefficient:

```
import  random
import  functools   as  fn
import  operator    as  op

# binomial coefficient C(n,k):
def cnk(n,k):
    p1 = fn.reduce(op.mul, range(n-k+1,n+1), 1)
    p2 = fn.reduce(op.mul, range(1,k+1),     1)
    return  (p1 // p2)
```

Next, let's compute t within the Python interpreter:

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jul 16 2021, 00:00:00) 
>>> 
>>> ks = list(range(5,8+1))
>>> ks
[5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> 
>>> cnk(8,5)
56
>>> 
>>> tas = list(map(lambda k: cnk(8,k), ks))
>>> tas
[56, 28, 8, 1]
>>> 
>>> t = sum(tas)
>>> t
93
>>>
```

So t is equal to 56+28+8+1=93, and we have 93 possible bit strings overall.

Let's now draw some random rank, between 0 and 92 inclusive:

```
>>> 
>>> import random
>>> rank = random.randint(0,92)
>>> 
>>> rank
77
>>>
```

So our drawn *rank* is 77. Let's describe the unranking process with this value.

The 56 bit strings with k=5 have ranks between 0 and 55, and the 28 bit strings with k=6 have ranks between 56 and 56+28-1=83. So 77 lies within the k=6 range. Specifically, it is the object of *combinatorial rank* 77-56=21 within n=8 and k=6.

Say we call that last number cbRank=21. Fortunately, the process of *unranking* a combination of k among n items is well studied; see for example this [paper by Genitrini and Pépin](https://hal.sorbonne-universite.fr/hal-03040740v2).

From the paper, we can easily write this Python function:

```
# Makes a list of the combination members from the combination's rank:
def combiUnrank(k, rank):  
    k1    = k
    rank1 = rank
    res   = []
    while (rank1 > 0):
        m1 = k1
        while (cnk(m1, k1) <= rank1):
            m1 = m1 + 1
        m1 = m1 -1
        rank1 = rank1 - cnk(m1,k1)
        k1    = k1 - 1
        res.append(m1)
    lRes   =   len(res)
    res    +=  list(range(k - 1 - lRes, -1, -1))  # pad with lowest values
    return res
```

And then we can use it to see which combination has a rank of 21:

```
>>> 
>>> cbRank=21
>>> k=6
>>> n=8
>>> 
>>> combiUnrank(k, cbRank)
[7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

So we've finally got our random 8 bits long bit string, where bits 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1 are set to 1 and the remaining ones, 0 and 4, are set to 0. That is, “01110111”. But this last process can also be automated:

```
# Makes a bit list from a combination:
def getBitListFromCombi(n, cms):
    bits = n * [0]        # get an all-zeroes bit list
    for cm in cms:                 
        bits[cm] = 1      # set the appropriate bits to 1
    return bits
```

Testing:

```
>>> 
>>> n=8
>>> k=6
>>> cbRank=21
>>> 
>>> cs = combiUnrank(k, cbRank)
>>> cs
[7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1]
>>> 
>>> bits = getBitListFromCombi(n,cs)
>>> bits
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

And by construction of the algorithm, all legal bit strings have an identical probablity 1/t of being drawn.